# Arduino NANO RP2040 Connect Serial Passthrough not working

Tags: arduino, esp32, rp2040

is it possible to do a serial Passthrough to the ESP32 chip on the Wifinina module like with the Arduino Nano Iot?

I tried the example sketch, but that does not seem to have an implementation for the RP2040 connect. The SerialPassthrough Sketch from the tools directory did not work withe RP2040 connect. When I try to use esptool on the flashed arduino I get write timeout, so the passthrough apparently does not work

Comment: the Tools/SerialNINAPassthrough example didn't work?

Comment: no, it did not.

Comment: so add specific information to the question. the name of the sketch and how it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, I updated the description